# How can I select an element based on its position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possible to select an element based on its position?

```
<div id="parent">
    <p id="text">This is a text</p>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
#parent{width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;}
```

Now using the left=100px,top=100px how can I select the div element using JQuery?

Comment: I am not a jQuery ninja, but I remember something about custom selectors... that may be one way of making it possible.

Comment: Are you trying to find element based on its top and left values? In other words, do you want to find all div elements with top=100 and left=100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
var el = document.elementFromPoint(100, 100);
var $el = $(el); // if you really want to use jQuery.
```

Documentation for [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint).

This might not be what you're looking for: it will only get the visible, topmost element at that point, and it will get whatever element occupies that space, not just one whose top-left corner is at that point. But, chances are, it'll help :).

[It is supported by all major browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t20), although you could get wacky results with Safari 4 or Opera 10.10.

Comment: is it cross browser compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through every element to check the position. Here is a quick sample function:

```
function getElementsByPosition(x,y) {
  var elements=new Array();
  $('*').each(function() {
    if($(this).css('top')==x && $(this.css('left'))==y) {
      elements[elements.length]=this;
    }
  });
  return elements;
}
```

Update: Domenic's solution is much more elegant. Please consider his before using mine.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment :). They do different things though... it'll depend on what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `css()` function allows you to retrieve the value of CSS properties, for example `css('left')` will return the left position of your element.

However, in your question you as about *selecting* the div element based on its location. I presume you mean something like `$('left=100px')`. This is not possible. jQuery uses CSS selectors which query the structure, not the style of the DOM.